# Merge left with mixed number of identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a maptable and a `df` where I want to apply a left merge to map an additional column on a set of one or more columns. However, in my case the available identifiers differ per row.

Here is an example:

```
maptable =

  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1          FX      EUR     t2
2       Rates      USD     t3
3       Rates              t3o
4       Bonds              t4o
5       Bonds      AAA     t4
```

Suppose we have the following df:

```
df =

  asset_class currency
0      Equity      EUR
1      Equity      USD
2      Equity      GBP
3       Rates      EUR
4       Rates      USD
5       Rates      GBP
6       Bonds      AAA
7       Bonds      BBB
8       Bonds      CCC
```

In that case, the desired result should be:

```
  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1   (we have Equity+EUR)
1      Equity      USD    NaN   (we don't have Equity+USD and also not Equity)
2      Equity      GBP    NaN   (we don't have Equity+GBP and also not Equity)
3       Rates      EUR    t3o   (we don't have Rates+EUR, but we do have Rates)
4       Rates      USD     t3   (we have Rates+USD)
5       Rates      GBP    t30   (we don't have Rates+GBP, but we do have Rates)
6       Bonds      AAA     t4   (we have Bonds+AA)
7       Bonds      BBB    t4o   (we don't have Bonds+BBB, but we do have Bonds)
8       Bonds      CCC    t4o   (we don't have Bonds+CCC, but we do have Bonds)
```

Simply applying a merge left on asset_class and currency will not work as the cases where one identifier column out of two has values, it will be ignored:

```
df_m = df.merge(maptable, how='left', on=['asset_class','currency'])
```

Also, very important, is that we need to overwrite in the case when a target col is already mapped if we are using more identifier columns. For instance, using 'asset_class' and 'currency' has more priority than just mapping on 'asset_class'. For this reason `fillna` will not work as we actually need an `update`.

How can this be achieved in an efficient way?

---

**Example data**

You can recreate the example above as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

maptable = pd.DataFrame({
    'asset_class': ['Equity', 'FX',   'Rates', 'Rates', 'Bonds', 'Bonds'],
    'currency':    ['EUR',    'EUR',  'USD',   '',      '',      'AAA'],
    'target':      ['t1',     't2',   't3',    't3o',    't4o',    't4']
})

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'asset_class': ['Equity', 'Equity', 'Equity', 'Rates', 'Rates', 'Rates', 'Bonds', 'Bonds', 'Bonds'],
    'currency':    ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
})
```

---

**What I tried so far**

Here is what I tried so far (but this is really rudimentary):

```
def merge_mix(dl, dr, target_cols, id_cols):
    """Apply a merge left with a mixed number of identifiers

    :param dl:  target DataFrame on which we want to map the target_cols, contains id_cols but might also
    contain target_cols. If non-NA matching target values are found in dr, it will overwrite the values for the
    index/col combinations
    :param dr:  mapping DataFrame that contains both target_cols and id_cols
    :param target_cols: list of column names that we want to map from the dr
    :param id_cols: list of columns that we want to use as identifier, can be empty
    """
    def is_empty(x):
        """Check if empty"""
        if x is not None:
            if isinstance(x, str) and x != '':
                return False
            else:
                if not pd.np.isnan(value):
                    return False
        return True

    # Append target col
    for target_col in target_cols:
        if target_col not in dl:
            dl.insert(loc=len(dl.columns), column=target_col, value=None)

    # Clean dr
    dr = dr[id_cols + target_cols]
    dr = dr.drop_duplicates(keep='last')

    # Loop over all the indices and check which combinations exists
    for index in dr.index:
        combo_cols = []
        for col in id_cols:
            value = dr.loc[index, col]

            # Add combination if value is not empty
            if not is_empty(value):
                combo_cols.append(col)

        # The combination for this index
        dr.loc[index, 'combo_cols'] = "+".join(combo_cols)
        dr.loc[index, 'combo_count'] = len(combo_cols)

    # Get the unique combo cols combinations. Take first the least granular and then work towards more granular
    # as we are working with .update and not with .merge
    combos_count = list(dr['combo_count'].unique())  # Unique list
    combos_count = [x for x in combos_count if x > 0]  # Take out zero count combo cols
    combos_count.sort(reverse=False)  # Sort to move the least granular first

    for count in combos_count:

        # For a given count, check all combo combinations with this count
        dr_cc = dr[dr['combo_count'] == count]
        unique_combo_cols_cc = list(dr_cc['combo_cols'].unique())

        for combo_col in unique_combo_cols_cc:

            # Maptable for given combo col
            dr_uc_cc = dr_cc[dr_cc['combo_cols'] == combo_col]
            dr_uc_cc = dr_uc_cc.drop_duplicates(keep='last')

            # Set index on the id cols for this combo combination
            id_cols_uc_cc = combo_col.split('+')
            dl = dl.set_index(id_cols_uc_cc)
            dr_uc_cc = dr_uc_cc.set_index(id_cols_uc_cc)

            # Update matching row, cols
            dl.update(dr_uc_cc[target_cols])
            dl = dl.reset_index()

    return dl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom function that defaults to checking just the first component of a tuple if the tuple consisting of both parts doesn't exist.

```
mapdict = {
    tuple(filter(pd.notna, (a, c))): t
    for a, c, t in maptable.itertuples(index=False)
}

def get(x):
    return mapdict.get(x, mapdict.get((x[0], ''), mapdict.get(x[:1])))

list_of_cols = ['asset_class', 'currency']
df.assign(target=[*map(get, zip(*map(df.get, list_of_cols)))])

  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD   None
2      Equity      GBP   None
3       Rates      EUR    t3o
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    t3o
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    t4o
8       Bonds      CCC    t4o
```

Comment: Almost there, how can we zip with dynamic columns? Eg if I have a `id_cols = ['asset_class', 'currency']` and `target_cols = ['target']`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) merge the two dataframes on `"asset_class", "currency"` columns obtaining `df_m`.

```
df_m = pd.merge(df, maptable, on=["asset_class", "currency"], how="left")
# df_m

 asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD    NaN
2      Equity      GBP    NaN
3       Rates      EUR    NaN
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    NaN
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    NaN
8       Bonds      CCC    NaN
```

Then obtain a `mappings` dictionary from the `df` dataframe corresponding to rows where the value of currency is `''` and keys in this dictionary are from `asset_class` column and values are from `target` column.

```
mappings = maptable[maptable["currency"].eq('')].set_index("asset_class")["target"].to_dict()
# mappings

{'Rates': 't3o', 'Bonds': 't4o'}
```

Now, filter the `asset_class` col from the `df_m` where the values of `target` col are `nan` and map this col using the `mappings` dictionary
obtained in previous step to create a new series `s`.

```
s = df_m.loc[df_m["target"].isna(), "asset_class"].map(mappings)
# s
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    t3o
5    t3o
7    t4o
8    t4o
```

Then using [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function fill the `nan` values of `target` column in `df_m` using the series `s`.

---

**Use:**

```
df_m = pd.merge(df, maptable, on=["asset_class", "currency"], how="left")

# {'Bonds': 't4o', 'Rates': 't3o'}
mappings = maptable[maptable["currency"].eq('')].set_index("asset_class")["target"].to_dict()

s = df_m.loc[df_m["target"].isna(), "asset_class"].map(mappings)
df_m["target"] = df_m["target"].fillna(s)
print(df_m)
```

**This prints:**

```
  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD    NaN
2      Equity      GBP    NaN
3       Rates      EUR    t3o
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    t3o
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    t4o
8       Bonds      CCC    t4o
```

Comment: I am not a fan of fillna iteratively, as this logic will not be holding when we have 1) more than 2 columns (it works fine for this example but if we extend) and 2) if we need to overwrite values (eg in the first step if we merge with 1 and then with 2 columns, we want the more granular case to overwrite the case where only 1 id column was used.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with your merged data first:

```
merged = df.merge(maptable, how='left', on=['asset_class','currency'])
```

That'll give you the first layer:

```
  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD    NaN
2      Equity      GBP    NaN
3       Rates      EUR    NaN
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    NaN
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    NaN
8       Bonds      CCC    NaN
```

Then do a `fillna` from another merge, matching the default value `''` for `currency` only:

```
merged['target'].fillna(df.assign(currency='').merge(maptable, on=['asset_class','currency'], how='left')['target'], inplace=True)
```

Which will give you the result:

```
>>> merged
  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD    NaN
2      Equity      GBP    NaN
3       Rates      EUR    t3o
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    t3o
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    t4o
8       Bonds      CCC    t4o
```

Needless to say, depending on your fallback value, you'll need to update `''` accordingly.  If it's `NaN`, use `maptable['currency'].isna()`.

One liner would be:

```
df_m = df.assign(target=\
    df.merge(maptable, on=['asset_class','currency'], how='left')['target'].fillna( \
    df.assign(currency='').merge(maptable, on=['asset_class','currency'], how='left')['target']))
```

Comment: Why not iteratively do the fillna trick on all the col combinations?

Comment: I posted a separate answer that somewhat follows that logic.  Not sure if that's what you're thinking? Efficiency wise I'm not sure which one would work fast, I don't have a proper sample to test the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is first check whether the particular pair of `asset_class` and `currency` exist in `maptable` first, fill the missing with default value (`''`), *and then* merge:

```
keys = ['asset_class', 'currency']
df_m = df.assign(currency= \
    np.where(df.set_index(keys).index.isin(maptable.set_index(keys).index), df['currency'], '') \
    ).merge(maptable, on=keys, how='left').assign(currency=df['currency'])
```

Result:

```
  asset_class currency target
0      Equity      EUR     t1
1      Equity      USD    NaN
2      Equity      GBP    NaN
3       Rates      EUR    t3o
4       Rates      USD     t3
5       Rates      GBP    t3o
6       Bonds      AAA     t4
7       Bonds      BBB    t4o
8       Bonds      CCC    t4o
```